# Picker in Xamarin.iOS available

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is iOS Picker available in the Xamarin.iOS? I have searched throughly but there is neither example nor information has been founded; however, it is available in Xamarin.Form.

Comment: I added a simple example...

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. It is awesome!

Comment: np, I learn by example and have a hundreds of these built as I learned Xammie 101 ;-) ...and still doing them, seems I found something new everyday.

Comment: Thanks a lot RobertN, could you please share the resources/sources of Xammie 101?

Comment: I've been meaning to clean them up and get them into my gituhb acct for awhile, seems something else always comes up... I'll add it to the upcoming holiday list

Comment: Oh I c. Thanks a lot again. Happy thanksgiving.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A real quickie example of a [UIPickerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIPickerView/): ([iOS SDK](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html))

[image]

Add a `UIPickerView` to your xib or Storyboard called `slotMachineView`:

```
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace Slots
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
                slotMachineView.Model = new StackOverflowModel (selectedLbl);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        }
    }

    public class StackOverflowModel : UIPickerViewModel
    {
        static string[] names = new string [] {
            "pscorlib.dll",
            "pscorlib_aot.dll",
            "Mono.PlayScript.dll",
            "PlayScript.Dynamic.dll",
            "PlayScript.Dynamic_aot.dll",
            "PlayScript.Optimization.dll",
            "playshell.exe",
            "psc.exe"
        };

        UILabel lbl;

        public StackOverflowModel (UILabel lbl)
        {
            this.lbl = lbl;
        }

        public override nint GetComponentCount (UIPickerView v)
        {
            return 3;
        }

        public override nint GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            return names.Length;
        }

        public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            switch (component) {
            case 0:
                return names [row];
            case 1:
                return row.ToString ();
            case 2:
                return new string ((char)('A' + row), 1);
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException ();
            }
        }

        public override void Selected (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            lbl.Text = String.Format ("{0} : {1} : {2}",
                names [picker.SelectedRowInComponent (0)],
                picker.SelectedRowInComponent (1),
                picker.SelectedRowInComponent (2));
        }

        public override nfloat GetComponentWidth (UIPickerView picker, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0)
                return 220f;
            else
                return 30f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SushiHangover:  Thanks for your sample code. I have 1 question. Suppose I have this scenario:  First, I want to dynamically pop up a picker when user click on a button, and then let users select a value from a picker and then close that picker widget after users finish picking a value from the picker. Do you have any sample code for that scenario ?

Comment: @SushiHangover:  I have just created a new question for my technical issue that I mentioned in my previous comment above. If you have some free time, please take a look at this question at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887140/how-to-dynamically-pop-up-and-hide-uipickerview-in-ios-xamarin-c-game

Comment: what is "selectedLbl"  in this line of code : slotMachineView.Model = new StackOverflowModel (selectedLbl); in the ViewController class

Comment: @JoeSleiman It is a `UILabel` that the code it updating as the user changes the picker values, review the constructor `public StackOverflowModel (UILabel lbl)` in the sample code

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand if i add a picker view from storyboard the name of the picker is "slotMachineView" right ? and from where i get the "selectedLbl"

Comment: @JoeSleiman In that case, you would have a `UILabel` on your storyboard that is named `selectedLbl` and thus an outlet would automatically be created for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.  The native iOS control is called [UIPickerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIPickerView/)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GenderPicker : UIViewController
{
    public TestVC() { }


    UITextField SelectGenderTextField = new UITextField();
    UIPickerView GenderPicker = new UIPickerView();

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        AddTextField();
        GenderTextField();


        Constraint();
    }
}
```

**Textfield To Show The Selected Data**

```
    private void AddTextField()
    {
        SelectGenderTextField.Placeholder = "Select Gender";
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.SublayerTransform = CATransform3D.MakeTranslation(5, 0, 0); //to Create a Space At The beginning of the text field


        SelectGenderTextField.InputView = GenderPicker; //To Start The UIPickerView from The bottom.

    }
```

**Gender Picke**r

```
    private void GenderTextField()
    {
        var genderList = new List<string> {
       "Male","Female"
    };

        var picker = new GenderPickerModel(genderList);

        GenderPicker.Model = picker;

        picker.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {

            SelectGenderTextField.Text = picker.SelectedGenderByUser; //Update The Selected Value In the TextField

            View.EndEditing(true);// To Dismiss the Picker View Once The User Select The Value
        };

     }
```

**Constraints**

```
    // Used Cirrious.FluentLayouts.Touch For Constraints
    private void Constraint()
    {
        View.AddSubviews(SelectGenderTextField);

        View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        View.AddConstraints(


            SelectGenderTextField.WithRelativeWidth(View, 0.80f),
            SelectGenderTextField.WithRelativeHeight(View, 0.05f),
            SelectGenderTextField.WithSameCenterX(View),
            SelectGenderTextField.WithSameCenterY(View)


            );
    }
```

**Picker Model Class**

```
class GenderPickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
    public EventHandler ValueChanged;
    public string SelectedGenderByUser;
    private List<string> genderList;

    public GenderPickerModel(List<string> genderList)
    {
        this.genderList = genderList;
    }

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        return genderList.Count;
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return genderList[(int)row];
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        var gender = genderList[(int)row];
        SelectedGenderByUser = gender;
        ValueChanged(null,null);
    }


}
```

[image: UIPickerView Example With TextField In Xamarin.iOS Gender Selecter]