# Xamarin iOS UiPickerView tutorial

Tags: ios, xamarin, uipickerview

I'm trying to find just some basic instructions on using UiPickerView in Xamarin iOS. There are questions here on Stack Overflow that answer certain questions, but I'm looking for just a simple overview and hopefully walk-through of adding the UiPickerView to a ViewController, wiring up the data, and registering events. As a noob to Xamarin and iOS, I'm struggling to catalogue all the places the code for this type of control need to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picker in Xamarin.iOS available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900884/picker-in-xamarin-ios-available)

Comment: http://sushihangover.github.io/xamarin-c-number-uipickerview/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXa9WZMcmoE

Answer (score 8):

// Set PickerViewModel to PickerView

```
var examplePVM = new ExamplePickerViewModel(myListOfItems);
YourPickerView.Model = examplePVM ;
```

// Create a PickerViewModel

```
public class ExamplePickerViewModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
    private List<string> _myItems;
    protected int selectedIndex = 0;

    public ExamplePickerViewModel(List<string> items)
    {
        _myItems = items;
    }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _myItems[selectedIndex]; }
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, nint component)
    {
        return _myItems.Count;
    }

    public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return _myItems[row];
    }

    public override void Selected (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
    {
        selectedIndex = (int)row; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice & tidy Good answer !

Answer (score 2):

```
// Textfield Click event
private bool OnTodeapartmentShouldBeginEditing(UITextField textField)
{

// Creating Picker view 
pickerView = new UIPickerView(new CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.X-UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height -230, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 180));
pickerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.From#d3d3d3;
pickerView.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;

// create done button
done = new UIButton(new CGRect(pickerView.Frame.X, pickerView.Frame.Y - 50, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 50));
done.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
done.SetTitle("Department List", UIControlState.Normal);

picker = new PickerDataModel(); 
if (departmentList.DepartmentDetail != null)
{

foreach (var item in departmentList.DepartmentDetail)
{
picker.Items.Add(item.Name);
}
pickerView.Model = picker;

view.AddSubviews(pickerView, done);
// value change event of picker view
picker.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
selectedValue = picker.SelectedItem;
txtDepartment.Text = selectedValue;

deptID = departmentList.DepartmentDetail.Find(x => x.Name == selectedValue).DepartmentId;

}; 
}
}
```

New Class File [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcvX1.png)
   // Picker Data Model Class for picker view , this class file is using on helper section for common use

```
public class PickerDataModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;

/// <summary>
/// The items to show up in the picker
/// </summary>
public List<string> Items { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// The current selected item
/// </summary>
public string SelectedItem
{
get { return Items[SelectedIndex]; }
}

public int SelectedIndex
{
get
{
return selectedIndex;
}

set
{
selectedIndex = value;
}
}

private int selectedIndex;

public PickerDataModel()
{
Items = new List<string>();
}

/// <summary>
/// Called by the picker to determine how many rows are in a given spinner item
/// </summary>
public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView picker, nint component)
{
return Items.Count;
}

/// <summary>
/// called by the picker to get the text for a particular row in a particular
/// spinner item
/// </summary>
public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
{
return Items[(int)row];
}

/// <summary>
/// called by the picker to get the number of spinner items
/// </summary>
public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView picker)
{
return 1;
}

/// <summary>
/// called when a row is selected in the spinner
/// </summary>
public override void Selected(UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
{
SelectedIndex = (int)row;
if (ValueChanged != null)
{
ValueChanged(this, new EventArgs());
}

}
} [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld1uU.png
```

Comment: as he is new so i am posting all related code so that he can't face other problem on it

Comment: I found the "not relevant code" very useful and important. Only thing I'm unable to use is the selected item

Answer (score 1):

This [PickerViewController file](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop/PickerViewController.xib.cs) in the MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop sample sounds like what you're asking for.

In particular, the `CreateCustomPicker` function [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/2551e963841bad6531069d7f574578b3bdc4abd8/MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop/PickerViewController.xib.cs#L141-L152) and the `CustomPickerModel` type defined [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/2551e963841bad6531069d7f574578b3bdc4abd8/MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop/PickerCustomModel.cs#L37-L69).

Answer (score 1):

[image: UIPickerView in Xamarin.iOS With Example Gender Selector]

```
public class PickerView : UIViewController
{
    public PickerView() { }


    UITextField SelectGenderTextField = new UITextField();
    UIPickerView GenderPicker = new UIPickerView();

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        AddTextField();
        GenderPicker();

        Constraint();
    }
  }
```

**Text Field To Show Selected Data From The Picker**

```
    private void AddTextField()
    {
        SelectGenderTextField.Placeholder = "Select Gender";
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        SelectGenderTextField.Layer.SublayerTransform = CATransform3D.MakeTranslation(5, 0, 0); //to Create a Space At The beginning of the text field


        SelectGenderTextField.InputView = GenderPicker; //To Start The UIPickerView from The bottom.

    }
```

**Picker Init And Setting Data**

```
    private void GenderPicker()
    {
        var genderList = new List<string> {
       "Male","Female"
    };

        var picker = new GenderPickerModel(genderList);

        GenderPicker.Model = picker;

        picker.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {

            SelectGenderTextField.Text = picker.SelectedGenderByUser; //Update The Selected Value In the TextField

            View.EndEditing(true);// To Dismiss the Picker View Once The User Select The Value
        };

    }
```

**Used Cirrious.FluentLayouts.Touch For Constraints**

```
  private void Constraint()
    {
        View.AddSubviews(SelectGenderTextField);

        View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        View.AddConstraints(


            SelectGenderTextField.WithRelativeWidth(View, 0.80f),
            SelectGenderTextField.WithRelativeHeight(View, 0.05f),
            SelectGenderTextField.WithSameCenterX(View),
            SelectGenderTextField.WithSameCenterY(View)


            );
    }
```

**GenderPickerModel Class**

```
class GenderPickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
    public EventHandler ValueChanged;
    public string SelectedGenderByUser;
    private List<string> genderList;

    public GenderPickerModel(List<string> genderList)
    {
        this.genderList = genderList;
    }

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        return genderList.Count;
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return genderList[(int)row];
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        var gender = genderList[(int)row];
        SelectedGenderByUser = gender;
        ValueChanged(null,null);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [blog post](https://www.casseykeating.com/home/2017/6/7/uipickerview-xamarin-ios) to cover the basics of a UIPickerView. It can be confusing, basic idea:

1. Add the UIPickerView to your storyboard etc, give it a name.
2. Create a class that extends from `UIPickerViewModel`
3. Set the model of the picker, `pickerExample.Model = new YourListPicker(YourList);`