# How to dynamically pop up and hide UIPickerView in iOS (Xamarin C#) game?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uipickerview, picker

I have seen a very good example of implementing **UIPickerView** at:

[Picker in Xamarin.iOS available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900884/picker-in-xamarin-ios-available/33902474#33902474)

However, my scenario is a little more complex than that because I don't want to constantly display the picker on the screen. Instead, I want to dynamically display and hide the picker in my game as needed.

Specifically, here is what I want to implement:

(A) First, on my game screen, when users click on a button called "**Choose Background Color**", I will need to pop up a picker that shows 3 values: **Red, Blue, and Green**.

(B) Next, users can scroll through the list of the colors inside the picker, and choose any of these 3 colors.

(C) After the users **officially** choose a color, I will need to close (or hide) the picker from the screen.

(D) Finally, I will display the color that the users select in step (C).

---

I think I can implement step (D) easily. But, my main question is this:  in step (C), how do we know **when exactly** the users finish selecting a color so that I can dynamically hide the picker ? The users may scroll back and forth many times to look at all 3 colors, and so, it may be difficult to know **when exactly** the users finally make a choice.

Or is it reasonable to expect that after users finish selecting a color, they will click on any space outside the picker ? Is it the standard behavior ?

Or, instead of using pickers, should I write my own customized **"RADIO BUTTON"** ? (Unfortunately, iOS does not have the standard radio buttons. Therefore, it will take a lot of time to design my own customized **radio button controls**...)  Or, can you recommend another iOS standard control for this case ?

I would greatly appreciate your answers to my questions or your suggestions on how to solve my technical issue.

Furthermore, if you can show me any sample code for **step (C)** or (A) and (B) and (D), I would definitely appreciate very much too. **Mainly, I am not sure how to handle step (C), which is the main point of my question.**

BTW, I can only write code in C# with Xamarin.iOS. So, it will be wonderful if you can show me the code in C#.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Create a `PopOverController` and in its view embed the `PickerView`. Give button `Cancel` and `Done`. Once the user clicks `Done`, you know now you his selection.

Comment: Sorry the `PopOverController` is deprecated, use `ViewController`s `PopoverPresentationController` to achieve this. You can even implement the delegates. So, once user clicks outside you can dismiss the `ViewController`. The delegates will be triggered. You can read the values.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.  But, still, Apple should have provided a different standard control for this kind of situation, such as a popup table or a pop up list that allows programmers to display a long list of items for users to choose from. In general, Apple lacks of many standard UI controls that are commonly available from other UI tools.

Comment: It is more abstract, so that you can create and embed anything you want inside `PopOverController`.

Comment: I would like to have 2 questions.  Is it true that both PopOverController and PopoverPresentationController do not have the OK or Cancel button ? Is it true that the only way to for programmers to know when to close or hide these 2 controllers is to wait for the users to click outside the controllers ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it doesn't have the `navigationBar` by default. At the same time you can embed the viewController into navigationController. Doing so wouldn't have any advantage.